# Django ImageField won't upload in function based view, but it does in the admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, imagefield

I've been trying to add some user uploaded profile picture to my website. **It works fine when I do it from the admin**, the image is showed and all the engines seems to be working fine (image going to the correct upload location and so on). The problem is when I try to do the same thing from my view.

I noticed that the *print("upload_location")* only appears when I do it from the admin. The weird thing is that **all the other fields in my Profile model are working fine** (like name "foo" is updated to "foobar") and not only in the admin, but in the view as well. **The issue is only with the ImageField.**

I believe it could have something to do with the way I'm handling the form.is_valid(), but I've been playing around with that and nothing changed (I know it is working to some extend, since HttpResponseRedirect is working.

Any ideas?

views.py

```
...

@login_required
def profile_update(request, username=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    user = obj.profile
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance = user)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profiles/{username}'.format(username=user.user))
    template = 'profile_update.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "profilePic",
            "nome",
             ...
        ]

    def profile(self, request, user):
        print('printing forms')
        user.uf = self.cleaned_data['uf']
        user.cidade = self.cleaned_data['cidade']
        user.telefone = self.cleaned_data['telefone']
        user.save()
```

models.py

```
...

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL # 'auth.User'

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    print("upload_location")
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.user, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True,)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True,)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(
                upload_to = upload_location,
                blank=True, null=True,
                verbose_name = 'Foto de Perfil',
                width_field="width",
                height_field="height",
                )
    ...
```

template.html

```
...

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </form>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add FILES into the form.

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = user)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/